# How to create pairs from the table

Tags: python, sql, pandas, hive, hiveql

I have a Hive table wherein data looks like this -

[image]

Each customer has corresponding accounts and the objective is to make intra-customer pair.
Pairs are based on whether the accounts have same year of birth or their first 3 characters of name are same.
Eg - Sam and Samuel.

The output looks like this - 
[image]

Ideally same account pair like AA, XX etc should not get created.
Also a pair AC and CA are both same hence only one entry of such pairs is needed. A pair can be formed on Name as well Year of Birth key but here also only one entry is required (can be anyone).

How should I approach this problem.
Test data for check -

```
create table customer_account(
customer INT NOT NULL,
accounts VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
yob DATE,
);

INSERT INTO 
customer_account(customer,accounts,name,yob)
VALUES
(1,"A","John",2001),
(1,"X","Tom",1996),
(1,"C","Harry",2001),
(2,"D","Sam",1994),
(2,"F","Samuel",1995),
(3,"Z","Jake",)1994,
(3,"G","Drake",1998),
(3,"H","Arnold",1993),
(3,"K","Yang",1990)
;
```

Comment: Please include your sample data as text directly in your question, not as an image. Preferably along with a `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for easy importing into a test database.

Comment: Just added the sample data for query.

Comment: Why is pandas taggged? are you looking for a panda or sql sol?

Comment: Data is huge (base data is around 25 Million). Hence I might have to take this into python (pyspark or pandas) cos for making intra-customer pairs the final number can be huge.

Comment: 25m isn't that big in the grand scheme of things (depending on your hardware and indexes), you could try in-db first unless there is fear of locking an operational system.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use substrings for your join in the HIVE language.  The logic should be sound though you may need to tune it for your needs a bit.

What you're trying to do is a unary (or self) join.  Below is an example of a type of query that can be passed.  You're essentially joining with an OR condition and testing that condition with a case statement to get the "Pair_Key". I used an inner join assuming you want only instances where matches occur.

```
SELECT 
     t1.customer as Customer1,
     t2.customer as Customer2,
     t1.Accounts as Accounts1,
     t2.Accounts as Accounts2,
     CONCAT(t1.Accounts, t2.Accounts) as Pair_No,
     t1.Name as Name1,
     t2.Name as Name2,
     t1.YOB as YOB1,
     t2.YOB as YOB2,
     CASE
     WHEN t1.YOB = t2.YOB THEN 'YOB'
     WHEN SUBSTR(t1.Name, 3) = SUBSTR(t2.Name, 3) THEN 'Name'
     else 'Issue'
     END as Pair_Key
FROM (SELECT * FROM Table1) as t1
inner join (SELECT * FROM Table1) as t2 --instance 2 of the same table
on (SUBSTR(t1.Name, 3) = SUBSTR(t2.Name, 3) OR t1.YOB = t2.YOB)
```

Without test data or more details of how far along you are, this is a start.

If the customer number needs to be the same simply adjust to:

```
on (t1.Customer = t2.Customer) and (SUBSTR(t1.Name, 3) = SUBSTR(t2.Name, 3) OR t1.YOB = t2.YOB)
```

Comment: By Saying Customer number needs to be the same - the idea is to have pairs within the same customer's corresponding accounts.

Like possible pairs for customer 1 can be AX, XC and AC (excluding the reverse pairs [XA, CX, CA] and same pairs AA, XX, CC).

Comment: I made an edit to account for this.  If you look at the "on" clause in the edit, it will account for this.  You just add a conditional statement.

Answer (score 1):

This does what you describe:

```
select t1.*, t2.name, t2.yob
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t2.customer = t1.customer and
        (t2.yob = t1.yob or
         substr(t2.name, 1, 3) = substr(t1.name, 1, 3)
        ) and
        t2.account > t1.account;
```

There is no need to fetch `customer` twice.  If you want "identical" pairs, then change the last condition to `>=`.

Comment: Suppose i have multiple such criteria's for making pairs.
So is it ok to use all those criteria's in OR condition in the JOIN criteria.
And within intra-customer pair same account pairs are not needed.
Like AA and BB for customer 1 aren't required.
Thanks for the directional flow.

Comment: @nOObda . . . You can extend this logic to match the logic you actually need.